# Skip a case in for loop and continue ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am doing an AJAX call in a nested for loop. Sometimes there is a possibility of going to error state. Is there a way to skip that particular case in the loop and continue the loop?  PLease help.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url : url,
     datatype: "json",
     success : function(data){
        // something here
     },
     error : function(xhr,status){
        // skip this case i and continue loop. Please help
     }
  });
 }
```

Comment: The loop will be finished long before the first error occurs (AJAX = Asynchronous Javascript And Xml). So, not possible.

Comment: @JavaJack but for me it keeps on loading(as a progress bar is shown while this for loop is completed) as in some case it goes to errors.

Comment: Yes, "it keeps loading", but the loop itself has been finished.

Comment: What @Teemu is saying is , the way this is coded, all of the ajax calls will be executed immediately. When the callbacks ( success or error ) are executed, the loop has long been done executing and anything you do or don't do in the error function won't prevent the other ajax calls from having been called in the past.

Comment: @Teemu is correct. However, this may help you in your future endeavors:

`for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
    if (i === 3) { break; }
}`

The `break` statement allows you to "skip" an item, then continue processing the loop

Comment: May be this will help you, you can decide when all the ajax requests are completed. https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f